# Different outputs on different ide

Tags: java

I am trying to solve the [Prime Generator Problem](https://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) using java.
My implementation:

```java
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
class Testtest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       int t=sc.nextInt();  //no of test cases
       while(t-->0){
       LinkedHashMap<Long,Long> hp=new LinkedHashMap<Long,Long>();
       long n=sc.nextLong(); //min range
       long m=sc.nextLong(); //max range
       for(long i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(1000000001)+1;i++)
       {
           long start=Math.max(2*i,((n+i-1)/i)*i);
           for(long j=start;j<=m;j+=i)
           {
               hp.put(j, (long) 1);
           }
       }

       for(long i=n;i<=m;i++)
       {
           if(hp.get(i)==null && i!=1)
           {
               System.out.print(i+" ");
           }
       }
       hp.clear();
       System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```

**Although my code got accepted.** But due to curiosity i further went on experimenting.
For input-:
           **2

             99990000 100000000

             99990000 100000000**

when i run my code on-:

1.[Ideone](https://ideone.com/4d2Qcj)
 
2.[Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide)
3.Windows Power Shell

I got the same results as expected on all three platforms.But incase of input-:

**2

999900000 1000000000

999900000 1000000000**

when i run my code on-:

1.[Ideone](https://ideone.com/AIIkrJ)-:run time error.
2.[Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/ide)-:getting different output for different test cases although inputs of all test cases are same.

3.Windows Power Shell-:Getting expected output.

Is there any problem in my code? Why i am getting different results in second input case?

Comment: What run time error do you get on ideone?

Comment: @Robert Ideone is no printing stack trace.On further digging, i found an online ide where code works fine [see here](https://onlinegdb.com/BylPQxyrr)

Answer (score 0):

Ideone has a time constraint for the execution of programs.

> Maximum execution time: 5 seconds (for not logged in users) or 15 seconds (for registered users)

With 10^6 numbers on the scale of 10^9, the program is likely timing out.

Answer (score -2):

ideone has a size limit. From the FAQ:

> What is the size limit for the source code, input and output?
>   64 kB.